# Allow tapping to click while typing?

Tags: 15.10, touchpad, synaptics

I am on Ubuntu 15.10, I would like to know how to enable tapping while typing.

**Edit: For some reason this is working as a workaround for now, and I can't logically understand how. *Just killing it does not fix it, just setting synclient and xinput does not fix it*, usually killing it makes the touchpad lose functions, but for some reason if done together, it works. This is a workaround for now, but I would still like a proper fix.**

```
#!/bin/bash
synclient TouchpadOff=0
xinput --set-prop 13 "Synaptics Off" 0
wait 20
killall syndaemon
wait 2
killall syndaemon
```

If I am pressing keys I cannot tap to click, I can still press down left and right mouse button to click and it registers, I can still move my mouse using the touchpad and it also registers, but I want to be able to *tap* to click while typing, it also disables scrolling, but I'm not too fussed about scrolling while typing.

I can tap to click at all other times except for when typing, I have no idea why it would just disable tapping but not clicking or moving the mouse pointer while typing...

I have tried checking Synaptics and my config is pretty much default:

[image: Synaptics General]
[image: Synaptics Tapping]
[image: Gnome Settings Daemon]

Xinput Props:

```
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
Device Enabled (167):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (169): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
Device Accel Profile (289): 1
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (290):   2.500000
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (291):   1.000000
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (292):    12.500000
Synaptics Edges (314):  1629, 5353, 1445, 4467
Synaptics Finger (315): 25, 30, 0
Synaptics Tap Time (316):   180
Synaptics Tap Move (317):   245
Synaptics Tap Durations (318):  180, 100, 100
Synaptics ClickPad (319):   1
Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (320):  0
Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (321):    282
Synaptics Two-Finger Width (322):   7
Synaptics Scrolling Distance (323): -111, -111
Synaptics Edge Scrolling (324): 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (325):   1, 1
Synaptics Move Speed (326): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.035874, 0.000000
Synaptics Off (327):    2
Synaptics Locked Drags (328):   0
Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (329):   5000
Synaptics Tap Action (330): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2
Synaptics Click Action (331):   1, 3, 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling (332): 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (333):    0.100000
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (334): 0
Synaptics Circular Pad (335):   0
Synaptics Palm Detection (336): 0
Synaptics Palm Dimensions (337):    10, 200
Synaptics Coasting Speed (338): 20.000000, 50.000000
Synaptics Pressure Motion (339):    30, 160
Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (340): 1.000000, 1.000000
Synaptics Resolution Detect (341):  1
Synaptics Grab Event Device (342):  0
Synaptics Gestures (343):   1
Synaptics Capabilities (344):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
Synaptics Pad Resolution (345): 58, 41
Synaptics Area (346):   0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Soft Button Areas (347):  3491, 0, 4079, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Noise Cancellation (348): 27, 27
Device Product ID (284):    2, 7
Device Node (285):  "/dev/input/event7"
```

I have tried

```
xinput --set-prop 13 "Synaptics Off" 0
```

and

```
synclient TouchpadOff=0
```

but of course it reverts back to "2" when a key is pressed. How do i force it to stay 0?

I cannot figure out for the life of me what to do.